# Crash switching views when adding data to a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

When trying to switch views (minus the two lines that add data to a property, it works fine. However with the 2 lines in (which is these two):

```
self.firstViewData = fvc;

firstViewData.passedData = @"hello test test test";
```

It crashes saying:

**2013-05-29 16:40:43.864 test [16166:907]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setPassedData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x325620'*

Whole segment:

FilterViewController.h

```
@interface FilterViewController : UIViewController
{
    FirstViewController *firstViewData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) FirstViewController *firstViewData;
```

FilterViewController.m

```
@synthesize firstViewData;

- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    fvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    self.firstViewData = fvc;

    firstViewData.passedData = @"hello test test test";

    [self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *passedData;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *passedData;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
@synthesize passedData;
NSLog(@"result: %@", passedData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `fvc` variable is a `UITabBarController`, not a `FirstViewController`. Look into how you set `fvc`.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for commenting. I set i up this way because when I navigated to the controller all that was shown was a black screen - is it possible to send the data this way?

Comment: @JoshBoothe Your method for passing data is fine, but you're passing it to the wrong object. Show us how you're setting `fvc`. And if you're seeing a black screen, you're probably not instantiating the controllers for the tab bar controller properly.

Comment: I see, `fvc` is set up as you can see above and then in the .h file there is `@property (strong) FirstViewController *firstViewController;` or is that not what you mean? If not let me know, on a steep learning curve!

Comment: @JoshBoothe You've shown us how you're setting `firstViewController`, which is just setting it to be `fvc`, but you haven't shown us how `fvc`, itself, is set. The problem rests with that, not the code you've shared thus far.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must look real thick right now, do you mean `FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];` as that is where I am setting it

Comment: @JoshBoothe Exactly. You've defined `fvc` to be a `FirstViewController` variable, but the controller you are instantiating is a `TabBarController` (whose base class is apparently `UITabBarController`). That's the first problem. If you're trying to get the first controller of the tab bar controller, once you have your tab bar controller, you'd probably do something like `fvc = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];`

Comment: @JoshBoothe let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30854/discussion-between-rob-and-josh-boothe)